# Given a binary tree and a sum, determine if the tree has a root-to-leaf path such that adding up all the values along the path equals the given sum

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I tried my own solution in C++ but there is a bug in the code. That problem comes from judge. 
So what I'm doing is keep adding a sum value and then check if the provided sum equals to the total sum in a leaf.

```
bool hasPathSum(TreeNode *root, int sum) {

    stack<TreeNode*> st; 

    TreeNode *temp = root;
    int SUM = 0;    
    bool hasSum = false;
    st.push(temp);
    while(!st.empty() && temp != NULL)
    {
        if(temp)
        {
            st.push(temp);
            temp = temp->left;
        }
        else
        {      
            st.pop();
            temp = st.top();
            SUM += temp->val;
            if(SUM == sum)
                hasSum = true;
            temp = temp->right;
        }
    }
   return hasSum; 
}
```

Comment: How can the while loop enter if the stack begins empty?

Comment: Are all the binary tree entries positive? If not, this is unlikely to admit a polynomial solution.

Comment: @Pradhan yes they are positive

Comment: @Pradhan Actually it doesn't matter. There are only O(n) such paths (one for each leaf), and their sums can all be computed together in O(n).

Comment: @NiklasB. Ah right you are :) Was thinking of a DAG.

Comment: @NiklasB. so what are my mistakes in the code?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? If you set a breakpoint at the beginning of the function and stepped through, you would have spotted some mistakes already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trivial to express recursively:

```
bool hasPathSum(TreeNode *node, int sum) {
    if (!node) {
        return sum == 0;
    }
    return hasPathSum(node->left, sum-node->val) ||
           hasPathSum(node->right, sum-node->val);
}
```

If you translate this to a stack implementation, you will see some of the problems in yours.  In particular, it is only at the leaves you want to check the sum (you check interior nodes).  You have to adjust the sum as you go up and down the tree (you always add to it).

Comment: how would I adjust the sum as I go up and down? I fixed the other problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean hasPathSum(TreeNode node, int targetSum) {  
        if (node == null) return false;
        targetSum-= node.val;
        if (targetSum == 0 && node.left==null && node.right==null) {
            return true;
        }
        int left = hasPathSum(node.left, targetSum);
        int right = hasPathSum(node.right, targetSum;
        return left || right;
    }
```